# How to send Client's Timestamp to Servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, timestamp

I am trying to get the time of the client machine when the HTML form is submitted. Currently I am using this inside servlet but it generates timezone issues. So to get rid of this, I decided to find the `Timestamp` in client machine and send it to the server when the form is submitted. Below is my code

**JSP**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>

        <script>
            function time()
            {
                 var elem = document.getElementById("hiddenTxt");
                 elem.value = Date.now();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <form action="TimestampClass" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="nameTxt">
            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenTxt" id="hiddenTxt" onsubmit="time()">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Servlet**

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Yohan
 */
public class TimestampClass extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

//        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
//        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(currentTimeMillis);
//        System.out.println(currentTimeMillis);
//        System.out.println(timestamp);

        String name = request.getParameter("nameTxt");
        long timeStamp = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("hiddenTxt"));

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(name);
        out.println(timeStamp);


        }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

However it didn't work, `NumberFormatException` is being throw for the timestamp field. So, how can I correctly send the client's timestamp to servlet and handle it there?

I have no idea whether the exception will do any help because I am sure it is happening because nothing is being passed to the servlet. Anyway, it;s below

```
Sep 08, 2015 11:09:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [TimestampClass] in context with path [/ForTesting] threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:601)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
    at test.TimestampClass.processRequest(TimestampClass.java:41)
    at test.TimestampClass.doPost(TimestampClass.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: what is the output of "request.getParameter("hiddenTxt")"..?  post your exception here..

Comment: Ok it clearly says your "request.getParameter("hiddenTxt")" returns an empty String ("") and you are parsing it to a Long value. so you're getting NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 2):

Add submit call back on form element

```
<form action="TimestampClass" method="post" onsubmit="time()">
                Name: <input type="text" name="nameTxt">
                <input type="hidden" name="hiddenTxt" id="hiddenTxt" >
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly the Javascript time also showing me the server time

Comment: May be you are running client and server on same machine or same time zone

Comment: No it is not. server is in amazon and my timezone is different

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `return` in your `time()` function.

```
function time() {
    return (new Date()).getTime()
}
```

I think you also need a `value=[time value]` attribute in your `hiddenTxt` field. Probably why the POST param is currently an empty String.

Answer (score 0):

Your "request.getParameter("hiddenTxt")" returns an empty String ("") and you are parsing it to a Long value. so you're getting NumberFormatException.

Let's start from your JSP..try following:

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>

        <script>
            function time()
            {
               document.getElementById("hiddenTxt").value = Date.now();
               document.getElementById('theForm').submit(); 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <form action="TimestampClass" method="post" name="theForm">
            Name: <input type="text" name="nameTxt">
            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenTxt" id="hiddenTxt" onsubmit="time()">
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="time();">
        </form>
    </body>
```

That will set the client time and submit the form on submit button click.

before convert it to long, check for the null:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
long timeStamp = 0;
String timeVal = request.getParameter("hiddenTxt");
try{
     if(("").equals(timeVal) && timeVal != null){
       timeStamp = Long.parseLong(timeVal);
     }
      out.println(name);
      out.println(timeStamp);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This way you can get rid if the NFException.